# Is Cobb-Douglas the only output function corresponding to a competitive economy?

Tags: macroeconomics, competitive-equilibrium, cobb-douglas

Apologies if this is a rather simple question, I appreciate any guidance.

> $$ Q(K,L) = AK^\alpha L^{\beta} $$
>
> where A is a constant. Identify the conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$
>   for output function Q to correspond to a competitive economy.

So a competitive economy is one where the factors of production are paid their marginal product. I am aware that the Cobb-Douglas production function alignes with this, so I would have: $ \alpha + \beta = 1$ and $\alpha, \beta > 0$.

**But is this really the only and most general answer?** I cannot see why we couldn't have different exponents and still pay the factors of production their marginal product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any constant returns to scale function is compatible witha competitive economy. Cobb-Douglas is not the only one. Google CES production function.

Also, product can be wasted or be an externality, so even in non CRS competitive economy can exist.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a+b<1,\;\; a,b>0$.  Pay the factors of production their marginal product:

$$rK = \frac {aQ}{K} K= aQ,\;\;\ wL=\frac {bQ}{L} L=bQ$$

So total payments to factors of production will be

$$rK +wL = aQ + bQ = (a+b)Q < Q$$

And the question is: **who gets the rest of the output that has been produced?**