# References on Cobb-Douglas Function

Tags: production-function, theory, cobb-douglas

I am wondering why everybody uses Cobb-Douglas production functions? Nowadays they are so standard that they are just written down without further discussion. Does anybody know more about this and can point to references on the discussion why the characterization of production by means of Cobb-Douglas is accurate?

Comment: Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: There are already similar questions with accepted answers on this site. Please see if any of these addresses your question: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/40017/42, https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/18998/42, https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/24366/42, https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/32016/42.